# Can't add events to iPhone calendar which are more than 1 year in the future

Tags: iphone, calendar, ios

My iPhone 5c won't let me add any events to my locally stored calendar that are more than 1 year in the future. When I add them, they stay for 30 seconds or so and then disappear. Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: Where do you store your calendar, locally on the phone, in iCloud, with Google or somewhere else?

Comment: Locally on the phone

Comment: I checked in my iphone5, it runs on latest iOS, and I don't see any problems creating events further in the future. It seems it's either calendar synchronization issue, or some odd glitch.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's some kind of glitch in your phone or settings are not correct.

I checked on my iPhone 5, which runs iOS `v.9.2.1` and event was saved even 3 years further. It's doesn't depend is it 1 year ahead, or 1 day ahead.

Try to troubleshoot:

1. When you are in a Calendar App, click `calendars` button in the bottom, and make sure the proper calendar is selected with checkboxes.
2. Check if the settings of synchronization for calendars are correct. `Settings`->`Mail, Contacts, Calendars`.
3. Try placing event to some other, closer date, closer than one year, if it doesn't work - proceed further.
4. Try a Restart. Press and hold the `Sleep/Wake` button for a few seconds until the red "slide to power off" slider appears, and then slide the slider. Press and hold the `Sleep/Wake` button until the Apple logo appears.
5. Try system update, check if there are newer versions of iOS `Settings`->`General`->`Software update`.
6. Resetting your settings. You can also try resetting all settings. `Settings`->`General`->`Reset`->`Reset All Settings`. You will have to enter all of your device settings again.

Answer (score 0):

"Reset all settings" finally solved the problem on my iPhone 6.  Note that I chatted and spoke with Apple Support and was ultimately told that the functionality simply wouldn't allow appointments over 1 year out.  Don't believe it.